# Print 'id' value inside the 'img' tag of HTML code using Beautiful Soup Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

From this code

```
id_image = soup.find_all("img")[2]
print(id_image)
```

which has result to

`<img id="nexperts-logo" src="images/nexperts.png"/>`

I want to print the id value only which is `"nexperts-logo"`. I write the below code

```
 for element in soup.find_all("img")[2]:
 print(element.get('id'))
```

but it does not printed anything. Can anyone help?

Comment: don't use a for loop, otherwise You are iterating over each character of what is `soup.find_all('img')[2]`, it would be different if You use just the: `for element in soup.find_all('img')` since then it would be a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate on `soup.findall()` if you're specifically addressing one of its elements. In that case you're really just iterating over the tag attributes:

```
tag_id = soup.findall("img")[2]["id"]
```

if this raises a KeyError then it's clear that you're addressing the wrong tag for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `for`-loop to get the `id` attribute. Instead, try:

```
id_image = soup.find_all("img")[2].get("id")
print(id_image)
```

Additionally, you can try using a CSS selector to get the `id` attribute from within the `img`:

```
# Will select the second `img` tag on the HTML
print(soup.select_one("img:nth-of-type(2)").get("id"))
```

Comment: Can I know why we cant use for loop? Cause before this I have used the loop to find the 'src' in the 'img' tag? Is there any different between the 'id' and the 'src'?